# How to pass a predefined javascript callback that returns a response, into a function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I need to call the same callback function multiple times, and so I don't want to have to repeat it, but it takes a response, and this response is somehow not available to the calling function unless I explicitly define it. Basically this is what I have:

```
// The callback function
function foo(response){
  //do something with the response here
}

// The calling function
mainActivity(data, function(response){
  // Upon receiving the data in the form of 'response', do foo to it 
  foo(response); 
});
```

What I would ideally like to do is:

```
mainActivity(data, foo(response)}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Have you tried `mainActivity(data, foo)` (passing it without calling)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple.

```
mainActivity(data, foo);
```

Though not if you're continuing to call `foo()` in `mainActivity()`.

Reasoning:

`mainActivity(data, foo(response))` calls `foo(response)` and passes that to `mainActivity(data, callback)`. If `foo(response)` doesn't return a function, it's not going to be very successful when `mainActivity` tries to call it as a function (which would be `callback(response)` in the notional declaration).